# Trying to get Maia chess engine to work with python-chess

Tags: python, chess, python-chess

I'm trying to get the maia chess engine (using maia-1900 weights https://github.com/CSSLab/maia-chess/tree/master/maia_weights) to run in python-chess.

I have the following code:

```
engine_path = r"C:\Users\brent\Documents\Chess\lc0-v0.28.2-windows10-gpu-dx12\lc0.exe"
weights_path = r"C:\Users\brent\Documents\Chess\lc0-v0.28.2-windows10-gpu-dx12\maia-1900.pb.gz"
maia_handler = EngineHandler(engine_path,weights_path)
board = chess_old.Board()
maia_handler.getBoardProbs(board, nodes = 1)
```

the handler functions come directly from the maia git page: https://github.com/CSSLab/maia-chess/blob/master/move_prediction/maia_chess_backend/uci.py

and chess_old is the chess.uci package (version 0.25.0 which is the one that is supposed to be compatible with maia)

The output of this should be a list of moves, along with the probabilities associated with each one. However, I get the following output:

> (BestMove(bestmove=Move.from_uci('b1a3'), ponder=None), ['b1a3  (34  )
> N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q:
> -0.00000) (U: 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'b1c3  (36  ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000)
> (U: 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'g1f3  (159 ) N:       0 (+
> 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'g1h3  (161 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'a2a3  (204 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'a2a4  (207 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'b2b3  (230 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'b2b4  (234 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'c2c3  (259 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'c2c4  (264 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'd2d3  (288 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'd2d4  (293 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'e2e3  (317 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'e2e4  (322 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'f2f3  (346 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'f2f4  (351 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'g2g3  (374 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'g2g4  (378 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'h2h3  (400 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'h2h4  (403 ) N:       0 (+ 0) (P:  5.00%) (WL:  -.-----) (D: -.---) (M:  -.-) (Q: -0.00000) (U:
> 0.08726) (S:  0.08726) (V:  -.----)', 'node  (  20) N:       1 (+ 0) (P:  0.00%) (WL: -0.00000) (D: 0.333) (M:  0.0) (Q: -0.00000) (V:
> 0.0000)'])

As you can see, every move has the same probability. I know the NN file I have is accurate because when I play on Fritz it works as expected, but I don't know what is causing the outputs to fail.

P.S. I also tried setting Nodes = 0. This gives slightly different output in which the N values and the WL/D ratios exist, but the P values are still set to 5% and the WL/D ratios don't seem to provide meaningful information either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't underwent the main problem, I just know that working with Maïa, the Lc0 client has to search with depth = 1. Maybe try to limit depth to 1 ?

Comment: Hi Brent, If you found a solution here, could you write your own answer?

Comment: @JacksonH Unfortunately, I was not able to find a solution. I ended up switching to the stockfish engine.